# Python, ChromeDriver and element List

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This should be easy... Let's say I have a list of elements that I have selected by a className.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.get("https://www.example.com")

users = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("userName")
    for user in users:
        print(user.text)
    tips = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tipText")
    for tip in tips:
        print(tip.text)
```

if I print out `users` and `tips`, I get a list of elements.

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="725826f32ff35a12c0e8760512aeb5b7", element="0.9805135317784113-4")>,...]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="725826f32ff35a12c0e8760512aeb5b7", element="0.9805135317784113-20")>,...]
```

But what if I wanted to convert that list of elements to text **without** looping and appending to another list? Is there any easy way to do that?

Also, if you can't... why can't you do that without pulling it from a list and writing it to another list?

I've tried `users.text` and `tips.text` and a bunch of variations on that, without success. This seems like it should be easy to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this counts...

```
users=[e.text for e in users]
tips=[e.text for e in tips]
```

But this should...

```
for c,e in enumerate(users):
    users[c]=e.text

for c,e in enumerate(tips):
    tips[c]=e.text
```

> But what if I wanted to convert that list of elements to text without looping and appending to another list? Is there any easy way to do that?

It does loop, but it doesn't append to another list. It just changes them in place.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the method I went with. I ended up using list comprehension to get it. My thinking is, since every item within those lists has a property, you have to access each one by iterating over it. thanks @WHACKAMADOODLE3000